# Point Questions For Set of R,N,Q and P

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, natural-numbers

I am compiling a sort of list of interior, isolated, boundary and limit points of different number sets for my knowledge. will deeply appreciate your input on this.

$\mathbb{N}$ - Set of Natural Numbers

- Interior Point
- Isolated Point
- Boundary Point
- Limit Point

$\mathbb{Q}$ - Set of Rational Numbers

- Interior Point
- Isolated Point
- Boundary Point
- Limit Point

$\mathbb{P}$ - Set of Irrational Numbers

- Interior Point
- Isolated Point
- Boundary Point
- Limit Point

$\mathbb{R}$ - Set of Real Numbers

- Interior Point
- Isolated Point
- Boundary Point
- Limit Point

Thanks in Advance.

Sid

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is $\Bbb P$?

Comment: Uhh... I didn't know that $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @LukasKofler It's a pretty standard symbol for irrational numbers (it's defined in the post now too). Topologists often use it, and $C$ for Cantor set (not $\Bbb C$; that is confusing).

Comment: I disagree that $\mathbb P$ is standard.  There are lots of symbols that are standard in a subfield, but are not standard in mathematics.  I expect that $\mathbb P$ is used informally by some topologists, but not when they publish (unless defined in that paper)..

Answer (score 1):

If we work within $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology; as a bonus I added topological characterisations of each as well:

$\Bbb N$ is closed, discrete in itself (so every point is isolated), but has no interior points in $\Bbb R$ so all its points are boundary points $$\partial \Bbb N = \overline{\Bbb N}\setminus \operatorname{int}(\Bbb N)=\Bbb N\setminus \emptyset= \Bbb N$$ and as a space in its own right it's the unique (up to homeomoerphism) countably infinite discrete space.

$\Bbb Q$ is dense, so $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$ and no open interval/ball of $\Bbb R$ only contains rationals; there are always irationals too, so there are no interior points and no point is isolated. So the boundary is $\Bbb R$: $$\partial \Bbb Q = \overline{\Bbb Q}\setminus \operatorname{int}(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R\setminus \emptyset= \Bbb R$$
and as a space in its own right it's (by a classical theorem) the unique (up to homeomorphism) countable metrci space without isolated points.

$\Bbb P$ is also dense and for the same reason as $\Bbb Q$ has no interior points in $\Bbb R$ and also no isolated points (so all points are accumulation points of it) and the boundary is $\Bbb R$ again:$$\partial \Bbb P = \overline{\Bbb P}\setminus \operatorname{int}(\Bbb P)=\Bbb R\setminus \emptyset= \Bbb R$$
and as a space in its own right it's the unique (up to homeomorphism) completely metrisable separable metric space in which all compact sets have empty interior (nowhere locally compact).

$\Bbb R$ is easy: every point is interior, it equals its own closure, the boundary is empty, no isolated points. It's the unique (up to isomorphism) separable metric space that is connected, locally connected and such that each point is a strong cut point ($X\setminus \{p\}$ has exactly two components).

Comment: Note to the OP:  we do not prove properties of $\mathbb N$ by itself.  Interior Point, Isolated Point, Boundary Point and Limit Point are all **with respect to** a larger topological space.  Every space has empty boundary in itself, but may have nonempty boundary in a larger space.  You may say $\mathbb R$ has empty boundary (in itself), but nonempty boundary in $\mathbb C$.